# Dedicated server - do SAS disks make a noticeable difference?

Tags: sata, sas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the merits of SAS vs SATA drives?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8997/what-are-the-merits-of-sas-vs-sata-drives)

I am running a linux centos dedicated server. Basic specs are a Intel Dual Core Xeon X3065with 2GB ram and 2 x 160GB Sata drivers in RAID1 configuration. The server is used for host a php/mysql application.

I am in the process of upgrading, which will have a Quad Core Intel Xeon processor and 8 GB ram. One of the options is to upgrade to 2 x 300 GB SAS drives instead of 2 x 250 GB SATA drives. My understanding is that spindle speed on the SAS drives is 15k.

Is there any noticable speed difference from using SAS drives, and is reliability on a par with SATA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, they run at much faster speeds, so your Random Access is a lot better, also they write/read considerably faster. Reliability is about the same if they are Enterprise grade SATA disks. (or thats what the manufacturers say).

I'd refer you for more info to [this page](http://blog.lewan.com/2009/09/14/sas-vs-sata-differences-technology-and-cost/).

Comment: There is quite a bit of either old or mis-information on that page. He's comparing 7.2k SATA drives to 15k SAS drives. Of **course** those SAS drives are going to outperform SATA there. Compare drives of like RPM, and there will be very little difference.

Comment: Sorry ErikA :( will try to keep that in mind for next time !

Comment: No prob. :) <filler>